# How can i use SUMIF to calculate a total in column M only if the corresponding row has data contaning text "OPEN"?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I use SUMIF to calculate a total in column M on another sheet only if the corresponding row in this same sheet ("TRADES") has data containing text "OPEN"?

So for example, I want the SUM of column M in sheet TRADES but only the rows of column A that show "OPEN"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0n45.jpg)

`=SUMIF(STATS!M:M, TRADES!A:A, "OPEN")`

Is what I currently have however, it returns "there is a problem with this formula" and I'm not sure what is wrong or what I can do to remedy this.

Comment: Your arguments are in the wrong order.

Comment: Hi BigBen, thanks for your help. Could you elaborate slightly?

Comment: Check the [docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) for the order of arguments. It should be `SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])`.

Comment: I have had a read and followed the suggested format and have used `=SUMIF(TRADES!A:A, "OPEN", M:M)` but it returns $0.00 which is incorrect. I think this is because not all of column A are 'OPEN'. I only wish it to SUM the contents of column M which correspond to the 'OPEN' ones in column A.

Comment: Are these two separate sheets?

Comment: If it returns `0` then either your values in M are text that look like numbers or there are spaces or other characters beside `OPEN` in A

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes the values in M were as you said, this is now fixed, thanks!